# React setState function in useEffect

Tags: react.js, jsx, eslint

I'm toggling a state when the browser is resized:

```js
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(true)
useEffect(() => {
  const listener = () => {
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1024) return
    setExpanded(false)
  }
  window.addEventListener('resize', listener)
  return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', listener)
}, [])
```

I've the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule enabled so ESLint complains:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setExpanded'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

How should I rewrite this? Or should I simply silence the ESLint warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You can include `setExpanded` in the dependency array.

**Long answer:**

The function passed to `useEffect` will fire only when at least one of the dependencies changes:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // runs
  // - on mount
  // - on every render
})

useEffect(() => {
  // runs
  // - on mount only
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  // runs
  // - on mount
  // - on renders where varA and/or varB change
}, [varA, varB])
```

You should avoid passing objects as dependencies, because they may trigger unnecessary re-renders. If varA is an object created on every render, it may have the same value but it won't be the same object, so it will be treated as change and fire up the `useEffect`. See the example below:

```js
const varA = { a : 1 }
const varB = { a : 1 }

varA === varB // false
```

However, sometimes, certain objects are guaranteed to not produce this behaviour, and this is the case of the `setState()` function.
According to the [React Hooks API docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate):

> **Note: React guarantees that `setState` function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders.**

This means that you can include it in the `useEffect` dependencies with no problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this the best practice to do? Didn't see anything like this in the React docs.

Comment: I would pass `setExpanded` as a dependency since according to the docs it's "free" for you to do so, but I think it would also be acceptable to pass an empty dependency array and silence the warning.